# GCM tmpClient.open(url) - "open" подсвечивает красным

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, почему open не распознаётся?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editText_user_name;
    EditText editText_email;
    Button button_login;


    static final String TAG = "pavan";

    TextView mDisplay;
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    AtomicInteger msgId = new AtomicInteger();
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    Context context;
    String regid;
    String msg;

    String name;
    String email;

    private GoogleApiClient client;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        context = getApplicationContext();


        if (isUserRegistered(context)) {

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChatActivity.class));
            finish();

        } else {

            editText_user_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_user_name);
        editText_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_email);
        button_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_login);

        button_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

            }
        });


        // Check device for Play Services APK. If check succeeds, proceed with
        //  GCM registration.

        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
            regid = getRegistrationId(context);

            if (regid.isEmpty()) {
                registerInBackground();
            }


        } else {
            Log.i("pavan", "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
        }
    }
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}

private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    Util.PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
    String registrationId = prefs.getString(Util.PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
    if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
        return "";
    }
    // Check if app was updated; if so, it must clear the registration ID
    // since the existing registration ID is not guaranteed to work with
    // the new app version.
    int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(Util.PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
    if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
        Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
        return "";
    }
    return registrationId;
}


private boolean isUserRegistered(Context context) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
    String User_name = prefs.getString(Util.USER_NAME, "");
    if (User_name.isEmpty()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


/**
 * Substitute you own sender ID here. This is the project number you got
 * from the API Console, as described in "Getting Started."
 */


private void registerInBackground() {
    new AsyncTask() {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Object[] params) {


            try {

                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
                }
                regid = gcm.register(Util.SENDER_ID);
                msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;


                // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP,
                //GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;/ so it can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
                // The request to your server should be authenticated if your app
                // is using accounts.
                // sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

                // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the device
                // will send upstream messages to a server that echo back the
                // message using the 'from' address in the message.

                // Persist the registration ID - no need to register again.
                storeRegistrationId(context, regid);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                // exponential back-off.
            }
            return msg;


        }
    }.execute();

}


private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
    try {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
        return packageInfo.versionCode;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        // should never happen
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
    }
}

private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
    int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
    Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(Util.PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);
    editor.putInt(Util.PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
    editor.commit();
}

private void storeUserDetails(Context context) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
    int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
    Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(Util.EMAIL, editText_email.getText().toString());
    editor.putString(Util.USER_NAME, editText_user_name.getText().toString());
    editor.commit();
}

private SharedPreferences getGCMPreferences(Context context) {
    // This sample app persists the registration ID in shared preferences, but
    // how you store the registration ID in your app is up to you.
    return getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(),
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}


//  private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() {
    // Your implementation here.


    new SendGcmToServer().execute();

    // AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest, "jsonRequest");

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client.connect();
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.aseke.goo/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.aseke.goo/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
    client.disconnect();
}


private class SendGcmToServer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute(); 
        name = editText_user_name.getText().toString();
        email = editText_email.getText().toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String url = Util.register_url + "?name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&regId=" + regid;
        Log.i("pavan", "url" + url);

        OkHttpClient client_for_getMyFriends = new OkHttpClient();

        String response = null;
        // String response=Utility.callhttpRequest(url);

        try {
            url = url.replace(" ", "%20");
            response = callOkHttpRequest(new URL(url),
                    client_for_getMyFriends);
            for (String subString : response.split("<script", 2)) {
                response = subString;
                break;
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //Toast.makeText(context,"response "+result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (result != null) {
            if (result.equals("success")) {

                storeUserDetails(context);
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChatActivity.class));
                finish();

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(context, "Try Again" + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        } else {

            Toast.makeText(context, "Check net connection ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }


}


// Http request using OkHttpClient
String callOkHttpRequest(URL url, OkHttpClient tempClient)
        throws IOException {

    HttpURLConnection connection = tempClient.open(url); // open подсвечен красным

    connection.setConnectTimeout(40000);
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        // Read the response.
        in = connection.getInputStream();
        byte[] response = readFully(in);
        return new String(response, "UTF-8");
    } finally {
        if (in != null)
            in.close();
    }
}

byte[] readFully(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    for (int count; (count = in.read(buffer)) != -1; ) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }
    return out.toByteArray();
}
```

}

В принципе код **okhttp** аналогичен с этого тикета https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33854040/cannot-resolve-symbol-okhttp

в build.gradle произвёл компиляцию таким образом:

`compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'`

Answer (score 4):

Изменились вызовы

```
// OkHttp 1.x:
HttpURLConnection connection = client.open(url);

// OkHttp 2.x:
HttpURLConnection connection = new OkUrlFactory(client).open(url);
```

В версии 3 этот код вынесен в отдельную [библиотеку](http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp-urlconnection/):

> Deprecated. 
>   OkHttp will be dropping its ability to be used with HttpURLConnection
>   in an upcoming release. Applications that need this should either
>   downgrade to the system's built-in HttpURLConnection or upgrade to
>   OkHttp's Request/Response API

.

Рекомендуемый код в версии 3.0

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url( Util.register_url)
      .addQueryParameter("name", name)
      .addQueryParameter("email", email)        
      .addQueryParameter("regId", regid)
       .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
       .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
       .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
      .build();

  Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

 if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
    throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
}

   for (String subString : response.body().string().split("<script", 2)) {
                newresponse = subString;
                break;
            }
```

Comment: Можете помочь с интеграцией в мой код? Благодарю за ранее

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего этого метода просто нет в версии okHTTP 3.2.0. Тикет, на который ты ссылашься, не новый, с тех пор могло что-то поменяться. Воспользуйся официальной документацией, либо поищи более новый пример кода, наверняка задача, которую ты пытаешься решить, решается не так, как 22 ноября 2015 года